# How to get Bean from a main code to the SpringBootTest?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have a SpringBootTest class:

```
@SpringBootTest
class EntryData1 {

    @Autowired
    private ItemsDAO itemsDAO;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        ClevertechTestTaskApplication.main(new String[]{"3-1","4-2"});
        System.out.println(itemsDAO.getList());
    }

}
```

When I call itemsDAO.getList() in test I get {}, but when I write System.out.println(itemsDAO.getList()); in the main code I get a HashMap. So that means, test class make copy of ItemsDAO Bean, how can I use the main one?

Edit:

Now I have @SpringBootTest(args = {"1-3","4-2"}) and made in main method getter of args, to see, if String[] args getts anything. I got {} from getter, so it means nothing was sent to args

Comment: You already have it , there is no copy. The line `ClevertechTestTaskApplication.main(new String[]{"3-1","4-2"});` doesn't do anything apart from starting yet another application which `@SpringBootTest` also does.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ok, now I'm sending args to main class like this: @SpringBootTest(args = {"1-3","4-2"}), but now it doesn't do anything, I still have {}

Comment: Are you using H2 db in test case?

Comment: @RohitAgarwal PostgreSQL, but it doesn't matter, as I can't send data to args

Comment: Ok is it possible to share code in repo to debug it further?

Comment: @RohitAgarwal https://github.com/Kernazhytski/ClevertechTestTask

Comment: I checked your code, it looks fine. Test case is working as expected. If you want to get data from Items table then you have to first load data in that table in test case. In H2 database this is possible with data.sql file.

Comment: @RohitAgarwal It can't connect to an existing table?

Comment: Yes you can but then you need to add same database details in application.properties file present in test/resource folder but this is not recommended to use actual database for testing. We should use in-memory database